# How do I block null in my localstorage key

Tags: javascript, local-storage, key-value

I dont want null in my localstorage key. How do I remove them in javascript?
I thought about:

```
while(true){
   localstorage.removeItem('null');
}
```

Comment: your loop never breaks.

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Just remove it once and it's gone. Is something adding it back and you need to keep removing it? Use `setInterval()` to run the code periodically.

Comment: Ok thanks but the code doesn't remove null.

Comment: Are you trying to remove all localstorage entries where the **value** is `null`? Your code does remove the one entry where the key is `null`.

Comment: Yes I want to remove every value null

Answer (score 0):

If you have stored a stringified Array and that Array contains `null` values you could:

```js
const fruitsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.fruits);
const fruitsArrayNoNull = fruitsArray.filter(fruit => fruit !== null);

// store back to LS:
localStorage.fruits = JSON.stringify(fruitsArrayNoNull);
```

Comment: But I dont wan't to delete the key, I want to delete all null values in the key

Comment: So, after *"deleting"* the `"null"` value, what should the key's new value be? `""` ? Or you want to delete the keys which values are === `"null"`?

Comment: Nothing, I want to remove them

Comment: Yes right i want to delete the values of the key which are null

Comment: What does it means? A key cannot hold a *nothing* value. Either you delete the key or you set its key to an empty string.

Comment: For example my key has 3 values and the Key name is food, first value ist Cherry second one is salad and last one is null. I want to delete null so there are only 2 values left

Comment: LocalStorage keys can only accept **Strings**. Not Arrays like you explained it. If you jave JSON stringified data as the value of your LS key... well that's another story.

Comment: I have JSON stringified the data

Comment: @JUNSKI in such case you should parse the String back into Array and use Array.prototype.filter()